# How to save array element names to the database?

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my model:

```
 public function getData($property)
    {
        $data = array(
            'a_4_1' => array(
               'RUB',
                'USD',
                'JPY',
            ),

        );
        return $data[$property];
    }
```

And in my view:

```
<?= $form->labelEx($model, 'a_4_1', array('class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label')) ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <?= $form->dropDownList($model, 'a_4_1',$model->getData('d_4_1'), array('class' => 'form-control')) ?>
        <?= $form->error($model, 'a_4_1') ?>
    </div>
```

When I save it to the database, it saves data in the integer format (e.g 1,2,..)
I need to save array elements' names to the database(e.g RUB, USD)(not integer numbers). How can I do it?

Comment: Controller code please

Comment: It is not related to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `array_combine()` to change key value of your array like below:

> array_combine($model->getData('d_4_1'),$model->getData('d_4_1'))

```
<?= $form->labelEx($model, 'a_4_1', array('class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label')) ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <?= $form->dropDownList($model, 'a_4_1',array_combine($model->getData('d_4_1'),$model->getData('d_4_1')), array('class' => 'form-control')) ?>
        <?= $form->error($model, 'a_4_1') ?>
</div>
```